# font family works only in html file

Tags: html, css

i load an extra font-style. but when i want to use this font-style, it works only in the html-file and not in the extra css-file.

[css]

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: sensation;
        src: url('./font/sansation_regular-webfont.eot');
        src: url('./font/sansation_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('./font/sansation_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
             url('./font/sansation_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('./font/sansation_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('./font/sansation_regular-webfont.svg#sansation_regular-webfont') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }
```

When i use this part in the css file, so it's not possible to set the "font-Family" in the css file or html file.

When i use this part in the html file with  ...  It works only in the html file?

What's wrong?

Comment: What does your folder structure look like?

Comment: Is your CSS in it's own directory `css/style.css` or is it in the same directory as the HTML? I would guess that the path needs to be modified depending on where the CSS file is compared to the font directory.

Comment: sh*t, thx that was the Problem, why i didn't see this Problem? lol thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using the wrong path to your font files. Paths used in a CSS file are relative to the CSS file.

Given the following folder structure:

```
/index.html
    /css/style.css
    /js/script.js
    /font/font.eot
    /font/font.woff
```

Your `style.css` would use `../font/` to reach the font files where `index.html` would use `font/` to reach the font files.